# How to convert user input into a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here in this code user can choose a color of a div. now in the original app there many colors from which user can choose and they will be placed on a template along side with a lot of other styling such as drag and drop text with different type font (italic, bold, times new roman, etc) my question is after user selected all these preferred styles how can i set the code to convert that into a file like a jpg or idk an object so i can email that div with all the added styling?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="myBtn">red</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div style="background-color:red;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: google javascript+canvas

Comment: try html2canvas library, does the best job converting html to canvas, and then you can get the image data as base64 string.

Comment: Looks like that's duplicated question see original one here: stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/… – Andriy Ivaneyko just now   edit

Comment: just a warning : if you want to generate email with the html in (not as attachment) and you have client using outlook. You'll have trouble. Outlook HTML rendering only works well with tables

Comment: thank you guys that was helpful.